# Meta Stack Overflow statistics graphs

Tags: discussion, data-dump, graphs

For the first time, I've created [statistics graphs for `meta.stackoverflow.com`](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/meta_stack_overflow/). Here's a couple of the distinctive "this must be meta" graphs:

[image]
[image]

Many of the graphs are disrupted a bit prior to the date when meta was introduced; this is because of all the old migrated questions from SO.

Updated stats pages for the whole trilogy are [here](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/).

Comment: How did you obtain this data? There still aren't any meta data dumps are there?

Comment: @Æther The February update contains meta (first time ever).

Comment: @pi: oh awesome; I must have missed the Feb announcement (it is here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/creative-commons-data-dump-feb-10/)

Comment: I think this is great data. But what are you expecting now - there is no associated question - so will this post ever be closed?

Comment: your link to updated stats pages does not work.