# "You must wait X minutes to accept an answer" When did this happen?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Has anyone else noticed the new (imo, good) feature for accepting answers. It appears that you now must wait 15 minutes before you can accept an answer to a question. Can someone point me to a link describing any more details to this change?

Also, was this feature requested somewhere or did Jeff just decide it'd be cool (I tried searching and didn't find anything)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste). The issue was people who were taking the first answer, no matter how bad. It's not even clear if someone who accepts an answer within 30 seconds of asking the question could have had a chance to *read* that answer, let alone check whether it is right. Giving 15 minutes for things to brew up should be fine for most users.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like March 27 according to the edit history [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste/44099#44099).  Another unannounced change.

Comment: that makes sense actually ... gives the users a chance to see the question and answer it in peace ...

Comment: @ldigas -- as long as it doesn't result in fewer accepted answers.  If so, I'd like to see it rolled back as the cure would be worse than the disease.

Comment: I can imagine only a small number of scenarios where that would happen. Got one in mind ? (generally, people should get the habit of accepting answers the next day ... gives'em the chance to think about them a little). ... except in the obvious cases of questions like : "what is that function called" ... but they make a small percentage.

Comment: @ldigas -- oh, I don't know, how about the legions of people who come here via google and ask a question anonymously, then get a new id the next day so they can't find their question again to accept.

Comment: most of those don't accept answers anyways. That won't change (unless we introduce mandatory registration).