# Why does it sometimes take 10 minutes before one can accept a valid answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Discourage questions being marked as answered within an hour or so of being posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post)
>   [“You must wait X minutes to accept an answer” When did this happen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44753/you-must-wait-x-minutes-to-accept-an-answer-when-did-this-happen)

Is this a function of how much reputation one has on SO?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Discourage questions being marked as answered within an hour or so of being posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post) or [“You must wait X minutes to accept an answer” When did this happen?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44753/you-must-wait-x-minutes-to-accept-an-answer-when-did-this-happen)

Comment: Because it's just courteous to those of us who sleep once in a while. If you give us at least 24 hours to have a reasonable chance of seeing your question, we might be able to provide an even better answer. There's no reason to get in a rush about accepting an answer.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's the same for all. You can't accept an answer in the first 15 minutes after posting the question.

The reason is that there may be a better answer posted after the first got in, so you don't accept the first rightish answer, but choose the best.

Comment: Will accept answer in 13 minutes and 20 seconds :)

Comment: It's useful to note that accepting a question tends to discourage other people from answering.  So once you accept an answer you have basically stopped the flow of other information and ideas.