# Stack Overflow: answers accepted too soon

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers

Many questions in Stack Overflow (and I'm assuming the other trilogy sites) have their answers accepted really soon, so soon I'd go as far to say *too* soon. I've seen questions with accepted answer that was *not* the best, which the asker even admits (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575819/sorting-dictionary-keys-in-python)). I presume this behaviour is namely from newcomers to the site.

Allowing a question to be open for longer encourages more, and perhaps better, answers; the quality of all the answers in question would be increased as users attempt to get the most upvotes and get their answer accepted.

I'm wondering if showing a reminder to new users when they post the question, or in the FAQ, would help. It's listed as a *guideline* in the [official trilogy FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about), but I wonder, who ever reads that?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste

Answer (score 6):

I think that the [15-minute window (which was just implemented)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste/44099#44099) is more than reasonable.  Any more than that and it's likely to discourage people from accepting answers at all.

If a later answer turns out to be better, the asker can always change the accepted answer.  And while accepted answers *may* discourage further (better) answers, that's not always the case.  I just opened up a question tonight where the accepted answer had a SQL injection vulnerability. I added my own (correct) answer. I don't really care whether or not I get the extra 15 rep points from an accept.

The accepted answer doesn't necessarily have to be the *best* answer - that's what votes are for. If an answer solves the problem at hand, then I see nothing wrong with accepting it. If it's a blatantly awful answer then it will probably get downvoted and any subsequent users opening the question will clearly see that.

It was a problem when people were accepting answers after 30 seconds - that's not even enough time to *read* the answer most of the time - but the current 15-minute limit seems to be working pretty well; I'd say leave it the way it is for now.