# Why do you have to wait 8 minutes before you can accept an answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

A user wants to [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707992/place-element-at-the-bottom-of-page-and-prevent-from-scrolling-using-css), but he can't, because of a delay of 8 minutes. Why must he wait?

See the comment at the bottom of my answer, please.

Comment: See [Allow me to accept an answer immediately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47448/allow-me-to-accept-an-answer-immediately)

Comment: @Arjun: Thanks for that link :)

Comment: 8 minutes is too long now? Kids these days...

Comment: @Ether, it's actually a block for something like 15 minutes, and the answer was posted after a minute. So, 6 minutes passed before the OP felt the urge to accept it. Kids are slow readers nowadays. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I imagine to try and mitigate the "Fastest Gun In The West" issue, where one person will very quickly answer the question, and another will take more time to giving more details. Obviously both are great for the asker, but if you have to wait a while to mark something as accepted you're giving the one who's putting effort into explaining the answer a chance. However, that's a baseless assumption, and I could be horribly wrong. :)

Comment: True, that's exactly why it was introduced: [Discourage questions being marked as answered within an hour or so of being posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste).