# You can accept this answer in 10 minutes

Tags: support, accepted-answer, popups, time-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why do you have to wait 8 Minutes before you can accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47814/why-do-you-have-to-wait-8-minutes-before-you-can-accept-an-answer)

Yay! I found my answer! Let's give it +1 rating and accept it.
So I click the +1 button and then I get this message:

> don't forget you can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking his checkmark

Okay, I'll do that! *Clicks the checkmark*

> You can accept this answer in 10 minutes.

Why?

Comment: -1 if I could… but I can't, daily vote limit reached.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H let me guess: too many answers accepted?

Comment: @Radek No, I upvoted hilarious posts.

Answer (score 5):

You can't accept an answer in the first minutes after you ask the question. I think this is because it allows for other people to give an even better answer before you jump to the first-best one and prevents two people, or one person with two accounts, to increase their reputation by opening and accepting phony questions and answers.

Simply wait the short time and accept the answer then.

Comment: True; but one does have to admit this is an odd usability problem.