# 10-minute wait to accept a question

Tags: discussion, time-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow me to accept an answer immediately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47448/allow-me-to-accept-an-answer-immediately)

Please, S/O, stop placing these ridiculous time limitations on Questions and Answers. Fair enough, you want to stop people from gaming the system, or maybe you're trying to save bandwidth. But there are other ways of going about it, instead of getting on peoples nerves.

Comment: I would like to delete my question. I must have sounded like a real douche when I asked it. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see graph and discussion here

> Anyone who accepts an answer within, say, 15 minutes of posting their question is almost by definition being lazy in a bad way. That is, they're accepting the first answer that comes along without considering all their options.

[Discourage questions being marked as answered within an hour or so of being posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste/44099#44099)

Comment: Then that definition is wrong. There have been numerous times when I have received a correct answer 2 minutes after posting my question, and implementation/testing only took 1minute. So, that's 7 minutes that I have to wait to be able to accept an answer. Okay, maybe it is laziness, but if the answer has been tested, and is correct, then why should I have to wait 10 (or 15 minutes, according to your post above) minutes?

Comment: Thanks for the link btw, helped me to atleast understand the reasoning behind this change. :-)

Comment: @j-t-s it's 15 minutes after posting the question, not after the answer has been posted. As most accepted answers are not even posted after 2 minutes (and most after about 6), it's often indeed just a 10 minute wait if it's *really* obvious that the answer is right. Just keep a browser window open, and after those few minutes ensure there's not an even better answer, and then contribute to the community by accepting the real best answer.