# Why can't I accept an answer immediately?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow me to accept an answer immediately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47448/allow-me-to-accept-an-answer-immediately)

I asked a basic question, and got a right answer in 1 minute. Why can't I accept it?

If I don't accept the question that is a problem: lower accept rate. If I would accept it, I have to wait 10 minutes unnecessarily. If I come back later then I may forget to accept it.

---

Let's create an abstract case:

There is a very basic question:

> Questioner: 1+1=?

The answer comes from A immediately:

> A: ?=2

The questioner accepts the answer in (1 minute!), because he/she checked it and that was correct. `A` can continue its work unless clicking on accept answer icon in every 30 sec.

B, who are browsing the questions list, will see, that 1+1 is already answered **and accepted**, and won't start answering the question. He/she may don't even open the question, because it is solved.
B see this:

[image]

Here is the feature request:

C, who is still answering the question first got a message, *new answer posted*. 1 minute later gets a new notification, the *answer was solved, here is the solution: 2*. C will not thinking about what can 1+1 be, but will chose another question to answer. And C won't post the right answer as a duplication.

PS:
I know that this is a duplication of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47448/allow-me-to-accept-an-answer-immediately).

---

Let me present the case if the answer is not correct:

the answer comes from A immediately:

> A: ?=3

The questioner accepts the answer in (1 minutes!), because he/she checked it wrong but figured out that is correct. A is happy that he found an answer so fast.

B, who are browsing the questions list, will see, that 1+1 is already answered **and accepted**, and won't start answering the question. He/she may don't even open the question, because it is solved. B don't know that the solution was false. B will still ignore the question though may know the right answer.

C, who is answering the question, will see that the solution is wrong. He will post the answer: 2.

A is working, because he thought that the answer is 3. One month later he will return back to Stack Overflow because this error caused a fatal error. After hours of debugging/or seeing C's answer found that 1 + 1 = 2. He will remember it forever.

Comment: Just because you think the answer is right doesn't mean it is. [Here is an example from an hour ago where the accepted answer was wrong on both counts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947559/performance-difference-in-where-statement/). If the OP had given more time for other answers to appear, it might not have been the accepted answer. Unfortunately the OP might already be off writing code that makes assumptions based on the wrong answer, and may not come back today, tomorrow, or ever to realize they've been led astray.

Comment: @AaronBertrand see my updated answer

Answer (score 5):

Because other people deserve a shot at answering the question. They may post a better answer, and those better answers deserve better than being trumped just because you can't wait a few minutes.

Not all questions are "basic". And the site needs to serve their needs too.

> B, who are browsing the questions list, will see, that 1+1 is already answered and accepted, and won't start answering the question. He/she may don't even open the question, because it is solved.

This assumes that B only saw the question *after* it was answered and accepted. SO gets a lot of traffic; many people will see the question between the time it was posted and the time someone answers and the answer was accepted.

Comment: ...and to delay people trying to feed socks with trivial questions...

Comment: If the answer is not basic, the questioner wont accept it in 10 minutes.

Comment: @user65130: You have more faith in some users than I do.

Comment: If the question is non trivial it will take more than 10 minutes for someone to write a quality answer.

Comment: @Servy: It depends on how non-trivial it is.