# Shouldn't an answer stay without acceptation for at least two days, to ensure that the accepted answer could be contrasted with others answers?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I find questions that are accepted less that one hour after. I think that the OP shouldn't be able to accept an answer before two days, let other propose alternative answers, detect hidden mistakes, ...

What do you think? Am I missing the spirit of SO?

---

Thanks to some comments I have found this [link](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/stats.html) very interesting.

Compare the charts Time of first answer and time to accepted answer. A chart of the difference will be really interesting and will show clearly that people don't wait to compare between different answers.

Comment: Acceptation? I'm definitely going to use that...

Comment: @Jon Thanks. It was a pleasure :)

Comment: Haha. I love *acceptation*!

Comment: @Downvoter Could see no reasons for your edit, and you supplied none, so I rolled the question, which is perfectly clear, back.

Comment: @Neil: Probably because the title is confusing. The phrase *answer stay without acception* doesn't roll very well.

Comment: Note that the "time to accepted answer" is the time between the question was asked and the (eventually accepted) answer was posted, and gives no clue whatsoever about how soon it was accepted.

Answer (score 4):

## No.

If the asker wants to accept an answer, they should be able to without limitation.

Comment: No, I like there's *some* time one has to wait (after asking the question, that is).

Comment: This. If the problem can be solved in 5 minutes, why should it take days to indicate that?

Comment: Either, because other could have an alternative that could answer your question better. Don't forget that the Earth takes 24 hours to make a tour. People on the other half can be sleeping.

Comment: @Vicente, even if that is true, most people ask questions as they encounter problems. I know **I** don't wait 24 hours before I start fixing a problem I have. I try everything and the first answer to solve my problem(without being a hack) I usually will accept right away and also implement right away

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a better answer or not, snooze you loose!

Comment: @Vicente: please remember, "accepted" does *not* mean "best possible answer to question" - it merely indicates an answer that the asker found sufficiently helpful. And, it *can* be changed, should someone on the counterweight continent happen to post something more useful...

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't think there should be any limit up or down on this .I do however think there should be peer group pressure, in the form of comments, to indicate when a user has made a bad accept, and to encourage them to wait. The number of questions where the user has accepted an answer that cannot possibly work, but is what they want to hear, is a bit frightening.

Answer (score 1):

An answer can't be accepted for 15 minutes after the question is asked. SO moves at a fast enough pace that this is plenty of time for peer review of other answers. Any longer and people would just move on.

Answer (score 0):

No, according to the discussion at the original feature request to [Discourage questions being marked as answered within an hour or so of being posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-posted/44099#44099), the current 15 minutes is deemed good enough.

(And see the nice graph at that question about how <s>quick answers are sometimes accepted, after the answer has been posted</s> the very quick answers are less likely to be accepted than those posted 6 minutes after the question was asked -- but still early answers are surely accepted more often than late answers. But: it shows the time that passed after the question was asked until the *eventually* accepted answer was posted, but gives no clue whatsoever about how soon it was accepted.)

Comment: I'm new on SO. How can I see this graph?

Comment: @Vicente: By clicking on the link in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The User can accept an answer if it solves the Question. If a better answer comes in, the user can always switch. If the user is not interested anymore, that's his problem.

Other people can look at the highest voted answers to see the alternatives, but the Accepted Answer only means one thing: The Answer that solved the Question for the person that asked.