# Does the delay before you're allowed to mark an accepted answer go down as you gain rep?

Tags: support, reputation, rate-limiting

Does the delay in 'wait xx minutes before you select an answer' go away as you gain rep?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you get past the [new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) it drops to [15 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44099/145982), but no, it never goes away completely. The rationale behind it is explained in [Time limit on accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer)

Comment: Thank you. Comprehensive yet concise!

Comment: and Sorry, I'll have to wait 8 minutes to accept :P