# When trying to accept an answer for my question, it is asking me to wait

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
>   [Time limit on accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer)

When I am trying to accept an answer for my question, I am asked to wait for 2 minutes. Why is this? I am trying to accept it soon after I got the answer from him -- within a minute. Is there a rule about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to allow others to post better answers, and for the community to give input on the answer via voting.

Point is, once a question has an accepted answer, fewer people visit it. The green box gives the impression "nothing to see here, move along".

So, the system makes sure you wait a bit before you accept the answer. There's no hurry, wait a bit :)

Additionally, it reduces the impact of the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)