# Would it be nice to be able to hide questions where answers were accepted quickly?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

For example someone asks a question and then accepts an answer a few minutes later.

Comment: Similar: [Delay before users can see answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175527/282094).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Every Stack Exchange site is designed to be a repository of knowledge in Q&A style. Each and every question and answer pairing is curated to last, so that future readers can benefit from the information provided long after the question is answered. Hiding any question, regardless of the speed in which it was answered, would be detrimental to this goal.

Comment: You seem to be saying (correct me if I'm wrong) that a reader should not value the accepted checkmark. Instead just see it as an indication of the asker's opinion and nothing more and read ALL answers on any question before making your own decision about the value of the answers. In which case I wonder why users don't have the option of disabling the checkmark.  Just curious.

Comment: Disabling our individual view/ability to see the checkmark, I mean.

Comment: @HenryM Um... I don't think I said that, or anything close to that... Your feature request asks for a feature to hide questions that quickly acquired an accepted answer, my answer brings forth concerns over a feature that would do such a thing. It has nothing to do with what a reader should or shouldn't do when reading a Q&A. But, if we're getting technical, the best indicator of a *good* answer is the answer's score. The accepted answer checkmark is an indicator for what worked best for the question asker, which is why the question asker is the only user who can accept an answer in a post.

Comment: okay. Right, the score means a lot.