# Is there any privillege or criteria that allows you to accept answers earlier?

Tags: support, reputation, answers, accepted-answer, privileges

I have seen users comment that there is a 24h time limit before accepting answers. But I asked a question on Stack Overflow which was answered within 2 minutes. I tried out the answer and it worked. So I accepted it and upvoted it after another 2 minutes.

How come it was possible for me to accept within a few minutes and the other user not? Is there a privilege awarded for that? Any rate limiting?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work does not answer my question. The answer below by @PatrickHofman is helpful.

Comment: Yes it does. Patrick only repeats what it says there in a short summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accept an answer after [15 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50703/245360) of posting *your question*. The time the answer came in doesn't matter.

This is a little different for self-answered questions. You can only accept your own answer [after 48 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6045/245360).

There is [no rate limiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/245360) beside these two rules. I guess the OP misunderstood another warning or error.

Comment: ok i understand that, but why do other users have to wait 24h? I answered a user's question and he/she commented that it worked. I said that if it was helpful the answer could be accepted and/or upvoted. But the OP replied that the site was telling him/her to wait for 24h. Or is it that the OP was lying?

Comment: Proof or it didn't happen. :)

Comment: wait I'll show you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127982/q-path-programfiles-my-folder See the comments in the question.

Comment: I see. There is no rate limiting on this as far as I know.

Comment: But there's no point for the OP to lie because he really accepted my answer afterwards.

Comment: I agree to that.

Comment: Yes, OP was lying, or more likely confused with something else he/she have seen. Your answer could have been accepted right when you posted it, without waiting. (since you posted it more than 15 minutes after the question was posted.)