# Incentive for providing improved answers over existing ones

Tags: feature-request

I'm looking at this from the standpoint that StackOverflow is not just a means to get an answer to a question (i.e. a forum), but so much more. Isn't becoming a *database of information* an additional goal of SO?

I've noticed being a regular user for a few months now is that questions that have received answers are buried underneath others that haven't received enough attention. I feel that some of my questions haven't ever been looked at once they were answered, even though there might have been scope for improvement. Users *who answer* tend to look for unanswered questions since they have more incentive to get reputation this way. Many questions end up with one or two answers and are then shelved with no further improvements.

Obviously, all questions on SO can't cover revolutionary, ground-breaking areas, and most questions tend to be *specific* to the asker. For questions that deal with instructions/steps on how to perform a task, such as [this one](http://nimal.info/blog/2010/latex-on-windows-with-miktex-and-notepad/), I'd say this blog did a much better job of getting a *complete, refined* answer than SO (or any stack exchange site) would have ever have done.

My idea is to provide some means for the asker to request improvements to existing answers, and users get alerts to these kinds of questions *with existing answers*. The feature would be something like a bounty, except that it shouldn't cost the asker reputation. The main aim should be to provide the community with a fine-tuned, clear answer that has been *built* with multiple improvements.

Does something like this already exist?

**EDIT**: Bounties are fine when the asker knows that his answer can be improved. What about when the answer is posted, the asker is happy, and **neither of them realizes that a better solution exists**? Everyone loses out here.

Comment: If it wouldn't cost reputation, everybody would do it. And once again, all posts would be buried in the masses...

Comment: @Dennis I agree, costing reputation is a way to ensure that not everyone does it. But the main problem is not how much reputation is lost, it's that existing answers are considered done and dusted in many cases. Only the really popular, broad-area questions are really improved upon. The specific ones tend to be neglected

Comment: I tried to answer, then I realised you said like bounties, but different. Sorry!

Comment: @Ninefingers Thanks, I just saw your answer :). Bounties are fine when the asker *knows* that his answer can be improved. What about when the answer is posted, the asker is happy, and **neither of them realizes that a better solution exists**? How would bounties help in this case?

Comment: @prrao they wouldn't, hence me removing the answer :)

Comment: I'm wondering if my question can be made clearer. If it can, please let me know or feel free to edit!

Comment: *"" What about when the answer is posted, the asker is happy, and neither of them realizes that a better solution exists*  Go to [philosophy.se]?

Comment: This entire question is based on the false premise that the *answerer* knows best. If your answer didn't get accepted, it wasn't the solution the asker liked the best. If your answer didn't get upvoted, it didn't help the community. Accepting and voting are different concepts which drive different behaviors and connote different meanings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One problem I have is that users accept answers way too quickly, and this is a disincentive for folks that are willing to come up with a better answer (which usually takes more time). When folks accept answers too early, the rest of the community assumes that they've solved their problem and won't bother to come back and look at new answers.

At odds with this are the people who beg and plead with users to up-vote and accept their answer within minutes of posting it.

These two things combine to make it much more likely that the first decent answer is accepted and that, even if better answers come along later, they are largely ignored. I think that's okay in general, even in the case where the OP ignores later answers, because hopefully the general public consuming the site as a dictionary of knowledge rather than a help desk will be able to glean information from all of the answers, regardless of whether they were first, accepted, have many up-votes, etc. I still get up-votes on questions that are years old, so I know they still benefit other users even though they weren't always the OP's accepted answer.

As a very recent example of this, this morning an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398587/sql-server-2008-foreign-keys-case-sensitivity/) was accepted within <strike>10 minutes</strike> (sorry, must have been 15 minutes, the "1 hour ago" always throws me off), even though the selected answer didn't actually answer the question completely. I've added a more complete answer (and commented on the accepted answer that it missed part of the question) but since the answer has been accepted I'm not sure how many of the original stakeholders will even notice.

I'm wondering if the threshold for allowing a user to accept an answer is too low, and if we should do a better job of balancing that between not having tons of unanswered questions and allowing more time for quality questions to be submitted. I'm sure this has been discussed at length here before, but I'm far too lazy to search for the threads. The one about time zones is relevant too because the person with the best knowledge about your problem may be 18 hours behind you, and you're missing out on a great answer because you've accepted a mediocre one (and they're not going to bother now).

Comment: So are you talking about a 'latency period' before a user's answer can be accepted? Has such a thing been proposed?

Comment: @prrao yes, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105695/increase-the-minimum-elapsed-time-before-an-answer-can-be-accepted - wasn't met with very warm reception.

Comment: Well, let me re-phrase - the powers that be believe that 15 minutes is long enough. Which means that the accepted answer is more likely to be someone in your time zone (or at least that keeps the same hours as you) and that types quickly. :-)  Personally, I don't think 15 minutes is long enough, and I don't buy that making someone wait before accepting an answer is such an inconvenience to them. JMHO.

Comment: It's really sad that people believe the answer they first see is the best one and that they can figure out the rest. I came across [a blog](http://nimal.info/blog/2010/latex-on-windows-with-miktex-and-notepad) that talked about a Windows batch file. People continually looked at it and suggested improvements

Comment: I still update blog posts I wrote 5 years ago, so I am the last person you'll ever convince that the first thing you bang out within 15 minutes is going to be top-notch. Unless you're Jon Skeet, I guess.

Comment: LOL I don't agree with a single answer on that meta question. I guess the timezone issue cannot be resolved, but getting better quality answers without the initial 'rush' for reputation is a pretty big concern

Comment: If your question is answered in 15 minutes, why wait a few days to mark it as accepted? Are you asking such horribly complicated questions that good answers can't be made within 15 minutes of your questions posting?

Comment: @sixlettervariables -1 What about people who don't happen to see a question the moment it's posted, but have a better solution? The best way to have community votes decide which answer is best would be to have a latency period before an answer is accepted. Currently, what tends to happen is that new answers are upvoted by users who *happen* to be on SO at that time, and users in another timezone have their answer upvotes pushed back

Comment: I answer questions that have an accepted answer when I have a better answer. Sometimes you'll get the green checkmark, sometimes you won't. Just because I believe my answer is *better* doesn't mean it was to the asker. I now see your problem, you believe the community *votes* on the *best* answer. Which is incorrect. The asker selects the *best* answer. See, this is purely subjective and non-technical; hence you cannot *solve* it for all cases.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I don't think that's the point. The point is that requiring more than 15 minutes can't possibly yield worse answers. And while *you* might go ahead and answer a question that already has an accepted answer, a lot don't even get looked at, never mind further answers.

Comment: @Aaron: if the first answer posted *answers* my question, why should I have to wait until other people answer?

Comment: I'm not suggesting it can be solved for all cases. But if the asker gets more answers because they didn't accept as soon as they possibly could, they get a better sample from which to choose the "best" answer. If they are allowed to accept within 15 minutes, they may accept an inferior answer, implement a sub-optimal solution, and never know any better because nobody who acts like you happened to view the question, never mind put in the effort to point out the flaws of the accepted answer, or submit a better one.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Why lose out on a *better* way to do something, if it exists?. Currently I believe the main problem with answers being buried in the masses and not improved is that users accept an answer, and others who *might* have answered with improvements don't even bother because they think the user accepted an answer and its not worth their time

Comment: @prrao: you misunderstand the objective for people asking a question. They have a problem and they want a solution. If they want to come back and take a better (for them) solution, they are free to do so. If they do not want to come back and take a better solution, they are free to do so. The current setup works, and it balances the Fastest Gun in the West versus *annoying the people asking questions*.

Comment: While delaying their ability to accept immediately doesn't really inconvenience them, it *can* help all of the other users who might benefit from a variety of answers to the same question. If more users have incentive to answer that question, they may not be any more appreciated by the OP, but the content will certainly be richer for all other/future readers.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I don't know about you, but if I asked a question and received an answer, I'd be **delighted** if someone voluntarily came forward and gave me a *better* answer. There's just not enough incentive to get this kind of response with the current setup. Isn't that the whole point of SE? To be much more than just some online forum where I ask a question, get an answer and move on?

Comment: The annoying part I've observed is that answerers want their accept rep right away and so they badger/condition the user to accept their answer. As a frequent user of the site, what difference does it make to me, the answerer, if my answer is accepted within 15 minutes of posting, within 12 hours, by tomorrow or by next week?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: it actually inconveniences answerers. Accept rates for drive-by askers will go down as they will leave with only a "thanks this helped" comment. Besides, the system already alerts users when new answers are posted and they are free to accept those when they appear. I also believe it is in the asker's best interest to accept the quickest complete solution and in the community's best interest to upvote the most complete solution.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I think you underestimate the disincentive for users to provide a "more complete" solution to a question that already has an accepted answer.

Comment: Exactly my point. The whole point is to give the community, not just the user a more enriched answer.

Comment: I found out about SO through a million *google* searches. That's where I'm assuming most of SO's traffic comes from. So that's the major point here. *Others* benefiting, not just the guy who wants his problem solved

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I guess we have different standards for "more complete". A complete answer does not have to be as long as this comment chain or even Dennis' answer. It likely shouldn't be. SO provides incentives for more complete answers by allowing the community to apply votes to answers. Subjectively better answers for the community will receive more upvotes. Subjectively better answers for the asker will receive accepts. If your novella answers don't get love from the asker, *it's because you're not helping them when they need it*.

Comment: @prrao: when you ask a question, your job is not to help everybody on Google. Your job is to get your question answered. When an answer comes along that meets your requirements you accept it. When you're a member of the SO community, your job is to upvote good questions and good answers, and edit questions and answers when needed. *Voting and editing* improves the site for Google visitors.

Comment: @sixlettervariables There are thousands of people out there (I know several myself) who have problems and are not SO members, or even know it exists. Can I go out to everyone and ask them to join SO? Google is the primary means for people to solve their problems, and it would be great if high-quality, *improved* answers from SO dominated those searches. That's my main point about helping others without any effort, not posting a question so that people can see it

Comment: @prrao: again, questions are asked to help the question author not every member of the Internet. The community votes and edits in order to help--indirectly perhaps--every member of the Internet.

Comment: I think there can be a balance. Not every question needs to wait 6 years before accepting the best answer, but I would venture a guess that very few questions get the best possible answer within 15 minutes. Besides, how can the community vote on "more complete" answers if those "more complete" answers never show up?

Comment: @sixlettervariables I guess our views differ. I joined SO with the hope that it would differ from all those badly formatted, cluttered forums out there. Looks like it's only marginally better than those

Comment: Also, I am not suggesting that a "better" or "more complete" answer has to be long or take a long time to write. If someone asked "How can I kick users out of a database?" the first answer might be "Reboot the server." That's one way, and it might solve the user's problem in the short term (if they're not very smart), but it's certainly not the best answer. If I come along 20 minutes later and the answer is already accepted, I probably won't even open the question to see what the answer was; I'll assume that someone told them how to set a database to single user mode.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: best possible answer for *who* and by what measure? And in your example if the accepted answer is that bad...answer it with something better. I guarantee you'll get upvotes and you'll help other people in the future. System works like it should, the asker got an answer and future visitors got an answer.

Comment: My point is it's impossible to assume that the best answer, by *ANY* measure, will always come in the first 15 minutes.

Comment: @AaronBertrand sixlettervariables is of the opinion that the asker's main interest is to get the *quickest* solution, while any one else who comes across that solution later on will want the *best* solution. This makes sense to a large extent. I guess that's why all those other similar questions related to 'unanswered questions' met with such lukewarm response

Comment: @AaronBertrand: and SO acknowledges that by making you wait at least 15 minutes...again this balances the FGITW problem with unnecessarily annoying question askers and ensuring new users accept answers.

Comment: The only problem is, how to ensure that users *continue* to post answers long after the answer has been accepted. This is likely something that will never be solved

Comment: @sixlettervariables the challenge is, like I said, that I am far less likely to even *open* a question that already has an accepted answer. If I took the time to open every question with an accepted answer to validate that the answer was in fact good, I'd never answer any questions, sorry.

Comment: I don't know that I agree that all askers are after the *quickest* answer. Some legitimately want to learn, and that isn't necessarily going to come from the first answer. But then when rep-seekers badger them to accept...

Comment: I'd really like to know, is there a question out there that addresses this **Exact** concern (**incentive to open every question with an accepted answer to validate that the answer was in fact good**)

Comment: If that's the case, we can be safe in assuming that people are really answering questions for rep, not because they care to impart knowledge

Comment: @prrao: exactly. If you ask a question, you want an answer. I believe there should be incentive to answer quickly and completely as much as there should be an incentive to provide breadth and depth. However, as you've noticed SE is not a forum. I'm of the opinion that encouraging the process of asking and answering to be long and drawn out will encourage forum-like-responses.

Comment: @prrao: if they didn't have reputation, there wouldn't be quality answers. SE would just be another forum.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: you can answer any question you want.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I totally agree with all your previous few points. From your standpoint, have there been questions where you got answers that you felt could have been improved upon?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: ...and flag anybody badgering for acceptance. Good answers will get enough upvotes to counteract somebody forgetting to accept an answer. Help vampires who don't accept answers will get less answers. It's not a problem to worry about.

Comment: Obviously if you *knew* that there might be a better solution, you'd have put a bounty on it. There have been so many cases for me where months later, I googled and found a better result.

Comment: @prrao: I don't ask a lot of questions, and I accept the first answer which solves my problem. I upvote any answer that helps or is also right. I don't accept an answer just to improve my accept rate and I've applied bounties when I want a better or different answer. If it takes more than 15 minutes to solve my problem, I wait for answers that solve my problem.

Comment: Why are you so confident that the person who knows how to solve your problem will be able to do it in 15 minutes? Are they even online right now? Are they monitoring your tag? Are they busy doing something else, maybe answering another question? Maybe it's true for you that you always get a perfectly acceptable answer worthy of acceptance in the first 15 minutes, but I really find it hard to believe that on average that happens for all questions. I'm not trying to convince *you*, because obviously you think the current limit is fine. Just expressing my viewpoint (which, by def, isn't wrong).

Comment: Yes, What sixlettervariables says only applies to people who ask questions once in a blue moon. In case you ask, say 1 or two questions a month (or more) you'll definitely notice that timezones/presonal incentive play a big part in answer quality and improvement

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I'm confident I'll get a good answer within the first 15 minutes because...well that's been my experience both as a question asker and answerer.

Comment: Well I'm sorry to inform you that your experience does not necessarily reflect the experience of all users, and I find it very hard to believe that you assume, never mind truly believe, it is the case for all users. If it were true for all users, why do we have so many unanswered questions in both popular and unpopular tags?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: because we have a lot of bad questions or overly broad questions. If you have an answerable question by a member of the community, it almost always gets an answer (and usually pretty quickly).

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree. My general experience is that while a lot of questions do get an answer within 15 minutes, a large percentage of those are not *good* answers, or ones that I would accept were I the one asking the question. And in cases where these first answers aren't accepted right away, more and better answers flow; however, similar questions with similar quality answers that are accepted early, don't get many (if any) further answers. (By definition, of course, this evaluation of *good* is subjective and this is based solely on my experience in the tags that I monitor.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I second what you're saying. I might not be the most active person on SO or the one with the most tags monitored, but in my case too, once a question is answered, people just don't bother any more to even *read* the question (I get this from the number of views)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm looking at this from the standpoint that StackOverflow is not just a means to get an answer to a question (i.e. a forum), but so much more. Isn't becoming a *database of information* an additional goal of SO?

Yes. Ideally, every question should have a perfect answer. Quite impossible, but ideal.

> I've noticed being a regular user for a few months now is that questions that have received answers are buried underneath others that haven't received enough attention. I feel that some of my questions haven't ever been looked at once they were answered, even though there might have been scope for improvement.

As long as none of the answers received any upvotes, your question will remain in the [`Unanswered`](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) tab. Also, the [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) will bump it from time to time to the front page.

> Users *who answer* tend to look for unanswered questions since they have more incentive to get reputation this way. Many questions end up with one or two answers and are then shelved with no further improvements.

That's natural. A question with an upvoted answer is considered answered. Gaining reputation shouldn't be the ultimate goal, but it's nice to see those little numbers rise...

But even without considering the rep, time is just better spent answering questions that haven't been answered yet. The other extreme would be having the community continuously improving the answers of the same questions, neglecting new (unanswered) question. That would be much worse!

> My idea is to provide some means for the asker to request improvements to existing answers, and users get alerts to these kinds of questions *with existing answers*. The feature would be something like a bounty, except that it shouldn't cost the asker reputation. The main aim should be to provide the community with a fine-tuned, clear answer that has been *built* with multiple improvements.

As I said in the comments, I don't see this happening. If it wouldn't cost reputation, everybody would do it. And once again, all posts would be buried in the masses...

> I agree, costing reputation is a way to ensure that not everyone does it. But the main problem is not how much reputation is lost, it's that existing answers are considered done and dusted in many cases. Only the really popular, broad-area questions are really improved upon. The specific ones tend to be neglected.

Questions that are *too specific* should get closed as *too localized*.

For all other questions, well... there are currently around `3,000,000` questions on SO. It's impossible to dedicate time to **all** questions. You have to draw the line somewhere.

Also, we have to consider the rate at which questions are asked. Taking the `500,000` newest question as a sample, SO receives `5,000` question per day. Even **without** an answer, most users won't even get to see a question after it's a few hours old...

> Bounties are fine when the asker knows that his answer can be improved. What about when the answer is posted, the asker is happy, and **neither of them realizes that a better solution exists**? Everyone loses out here.

Not true. You can put a bounty on **any** question on SO, not just your own.

Comment: Sure, there are 3 million questions, but how many of those are in tags/areas where you are comfortable answering? Even the volume in the sql-server* tags is overwhelming, but I don't focus on only unanswered questions in the strict sense (meaning no answer with an up-vote). Depending on volume, time of day and schedule, I often look at questions that have answers (with or without up-votes). But I very rarely look at questions with *accepted* answers, unless the title is very intriguing.

Comment: Exactly my point. Depending on how busy I am, I end up looking at answered questions (yet unaccepted), but would rarely end up trying to improve an accepted solution that I'm not sure will *ever* be looked at. Ten months down the line, some other poor soul facing a similar problem might end up missing out on what could have been a vastly improved, complete answer

Comment: @AaronBertrand: There are almost `500,000` questions in my three favorite tags, `300` of which were posted in the last 6 hours. If **without** an answer, the chances that I even see a slightly older question are small.

Comment: Maybe you need to narrow your filtering. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand: That's just `[php]`, `[javascript]` and `[c]`. There isn't much activity in `[c]`, and the first two aren't even the most popular tags.

Comment: @Dennis I understand there are a lot of questions, but that doesn't make quantity > quality. So what if there are 10,000,000 questions here with 99% of them having crappy answers? Does that meld with the SE goal?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I'm not saying the current situation is ideal. But the solution the OP proposes (bounties that don't cost any rep) won't make it better. And I can't think of any change myself that could make question with existing but less then perfect answers stick out.

Comment: Agreed, I don't think a "free bounty" is better. But I think there could be improvements in (a) the time required before I can accept an answer, and (b) the criteria that make an answer show up under "unanswered." My interpretation of "unanswered" is not that a question hasn't received at least one answer with an upvote, it's that the question does not have an *accepted* answer. Maybe there needs to be two ways to express those. I'm far more interested in the union than just the former.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think my question's been answered. I agree, the free bounty idea is not the best. Is there an existing question similar to what you suggested, and if not, is there a way to open this up as a separate question? Thanks to you both!

Comment: @prrao: [Increase the minimum elapsed time before an answer can be accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105695/increase-the-minimum-elapsed-time-before-an-answer-can-be-accepted)

Comment: @Dennis Sorry I meant the second option: Interpretation of 'unanswered'. My searches are giving ambiguous results

Comment: @Dennis I pointed to that question too, unfortunately it's long been forgotten because the "answer" was that there *was* a 15-minute limit instituted, the OP was just not looking at recent questions. I think a new question would be, "Can we increase the 15-minute limit?"

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I think a distinction by accepted answer would have too many false positives. There are thousands of questions with a perfectly valid answer that wasn't accepted.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I was also interested in the second point you made. A large part of the problem is that questions *without* accepted answers (but with answers nonetheless) don't show up in 'unanswered' searches. This *must* surely be having an impact on the quality of answers in general

Comment: @Dennis That's a valid point too. Damn, this one's hard

Comment: @Dennis there are also thousands of questions with poor answers that happen to be accepted, and thousands of crappy questions with no answers because they're crappy questions and haven't yet been closed - this was discussed recently here because on some low-volume tags crappy questions stay open a lot longer. What filtering makes sense to you depends on what type of questions you are trying to answer. Note: our filtering preferences may not be the same.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I agree. But there already is a way to search for questions without accepted answers (`hasaccepted:1`), so why **remove** a functionality from SO by setting `unanswered == no accepted answer`?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting removing a functionality. I was suggesting that there be two different ways to search for unanswered as currently defined and unanswered how I propose it be define ("unaccepted" perhaps). Without having to know the search jargon/syntax.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: My bad, I thought you wanted to replace the button (rather than adding a new one). Still, adding the users that aim at `100%` accept rate to those that ask a question here and don't even bother to come back to check for answers, I don't think that `unaccepted` is a reliable indicator. Maybe increasing the threshold to answers with a score of `X` would be better. That way, the community can at least use votes to mark a question as (un)answered.