# Accepting too many answers too fast?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I recently commented on a SO question that was borderline debate/discussion oriented.

In doing so, I also noted the asker only had a 47% accept rate, despite an otherwise respectable 3.5k rep, more than 150 questions and a good collection of badges.

He replied to say he'd been on other SE sites of late and needed to catch up, before proceeding to work his way through his questions, accepting a lot of answers within a few minutes to bring his accept rate to just under 70%.

I felt that my observation had backfired somewhat - instead of just having a low accept rate, he's now gone rushing through his questions, presumably clicking on the highest-rated one on each, rather than considering each collection of answers to pick out the one that was most helpful or correct.

I know there's a strong correlation between highest-voted and most 'correct' or helpful, but there are plenty of examples where this isn't the case (despite the reward the Populist badge offers).

Is there an in-built mechanism to prevent *too many* answers from being accepted too quickly? I.e. to ensure that accepted answers are being thought about rather than blindly accepted? After all, the point of accepting an answer isn't *just* to award points for everyone, is it?

And if no such check exists... should it?

Comment: +1 for asking about the behavior, not the Feature-Request.

Comment: As an aside: for newly posted questions, one needs to [wait 15 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste/44099#44099) after posting the question.

Comment: @Arjan I was aware of that rule, but this is almost the inverse - many answers from weeks/months in the past being accepted "in bulk" within a few minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though the user ran through his list of questions and answered them too quickly in your opinion, accepting an answer to a question is still a personal decision-- which answer to select, if any.

If the user truly "cares" about which post answered his question, they always have the ability to change the selected answer later.

If there is a better answer in the post than the accepted answer, then presumably community members would have or will be upvoting that answer more than the accepted answer.  Either way, it feels like the system still works.  Accepting answers too fast just doesn't seem to be a problem, in my opinion.