# Why is there a 15 minute timer until you can accept an answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Sometimes, you ask a question and you are lucky enough to get an answer in one or two minutes. I don't understand why I have to wait for 15 minutes before I can accept the answer if it solves my problem. To be honest, the most annoying part about this is having to keep an extra tab open in my browser for 15 minutes until I can accept it.

Now, according to [Jeff's reasoning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post/44099#44099), "they're accepting the first answer that comes along without considering all their options."

This is not always true. Now, on a website such as stackoverflow (I'm only posting it on the stackoverflow meta because meta.stackexchange redirects here so I'm assuming it's the "general" meta) there is a good reason for this timer. **However,** on a website such as superuser, where a lot of problems are of broken things, if people offer a solution that fixes their issue, there's no point in waiting 15 minutes, **their problem has been fixed and their question has been answered.**

Comment: And what's the problem with waiting 15 minutes? Or even giving it a day? There is no rush.

Answer (score 8):

Jeff's reason is enough for the timer setting. You stated that *This is not always true*. So, you accept that this method is needed in some cases. And you need to know that if the OP accept the first answer means the system will show a green color coding on the number of answers to the post. Then the answerers won't be intend to see the post. who knows the OP can get an alternate/better solution and the OP need some time check the answer is correct or not.

Comment: It might be time to implement a "check-if-this-question-needs-15-minutes-before-an-answer-can-be-accepted" script :)

Answer (score 3):

I would say it is a combination of preventing karma farming (people simply asking questions and immediately accepting answers) and also to allow people to consider more answers before jumping the gun.

I don't think your argument is very valid... You say what is the point of waiting 15 minutes if the answer posted solves your question. Well why exactly do you need to accept the answer immediately? The StackExchange is about accepting the **BEST** answer. While someone may provide a solution that solves your problem, there may be someone who comes along who gives not only a more efficient and elegant answer, but also an explanation along with it. Too many times I have seen questions that have accepted answers, and I scroll down I find a far superior answer but it does not get as much attention because of a silly green checkmark.

Ideally, you shouldn't be accepting any answer that solves your problem -- you should be accepting the answer that solves your problem and provides the most amount information regarding the problem for the sake of the StackExchange community.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing one of your concerns:

> the most annoying part about this is having to keep an extra tab open in my browser for 15 minutes until I can accept it

You don't have to leave your tab open. You can keep track of your questions in your profile or even better you can look for your own questions by searching `user:me is:question hasaccepted:no` in SO (you can even bookmark it).

Another thing to keep in mind is, there is *no hurry*. The answerer/community isn't expecting you to accept an answer immediately. Even if you accept the answer a day or two later, all is good. In the meanwhile, you can up-vote answer(s) that you find helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Because you can check whether an answer is good/helpful/solving the problem or not in 15 minutes.