# Should the functionality of Accept this Answer be changed?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

A user asks a question to get an answer after a lot of research. They get the first answer, but it's not explained or detailed at all. As the asker did a lot of research on the question, he already understood the answer and therefore accepted that as the answer.

The user didn't get an answer anywhere else before, so this will be an important Q&A thread online.

Perhaps the questions without accepted answers may be the first priority for an answerer.

In the above situation, if the answer is not accepted quickly, then there may be more chance that the question will get more answers. So does the process of quickly accepting an answer degrade a thread?

If it is right, I'm suggesting a feature that an answered question gets more answers with the same importance shown to the OP.

Comment: Hmm? I don't follow any of this. Do you want a *double*-accept or something like that?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191755/can-we-stop-rushing-people-to-accept-an-answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93800/deciding-what-answer-to-accept-the-correct-one-liner-or-the-later-elaborate-one

Comment: Why did you roll back the edit?

Comment: i asked "is that right to improve the functionality?" and you said "change the functionality". Both are different. But i don't know how this changes are working with out questioner approval..

Comment: I changed the title because the question is tagged with **[tag:discussion]** therefore the question title is a prompt for discussion, ie. 'should we change the functionality?' which sums up your question pretty well in my opinion. If you want to be like that, your choice, but don't expect more help if you do that. I'm not going to engage in an edit war.

Comment: @Tim no idea...

Comment: Yes. its discussion. i understood.

Comment: @Jeet i've edited again because the English was quite bad. Honestly, it's better.

Comment: Yes i understood and i know about my english writing. So i left doing rollback the content. And did only rollback the title. Thanks

Comment: ok. let me see the impact.

Comment: After editing both content & title are perfect now. Yes it helped to say the thoughts very clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there's already a little limit: to accept, you have to wait 15 mins since you ask.

Also, the most important input in judging the post usefulness and quality does the community by up/downvoting. The accept mark doesn't necessary discourage further answers, because normal question shouldn't be relevant only to the OP, but to anyone other. Because by accepting, OP marks the answer which *helped them*, and community votes to show whether this answer *is helpful to others*.