# When was the time limit for accepting an answer after 15 minutes implemented?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I understand there is a policy of how long before an answer can be accepted.

I would like to know **when exactly this policy was put into place**?
And does this rule vary depending on the op's reputation ?

I will explain a bit to give a purpose of the question. The intent of putting the 15 minutes rule is to avoid discouraging others to contribute. I did a very crude test of the effect of the rule. I plotted the distribution of how many answers each question get in the month before and after the 2010/03/27. The distribution barely changed. To say the least, my method did not show the 15 min rule did not have a significant impact on people's willingness to contribute. I am willing to do more tests of the rule. Perhaps you could suggest some. I think this question is still within the spirit of the meta site. I am trying to help the site understand its rule.

Comment: This is mentioned in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide ; TL;DR: 15 minutes before accepting another person's answer, 48 hours before accepting your own

Comment: The link is wrong. I would like to have an exact date of the policy change. And is it always 15 minutes for every type of answer , user etc ?

Comment: The link is edited. I copy/pasted the wrong thing.

Comment: It does not solve my question. I know the policy. I want to know when it started to be effective.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### 15 minute delay

The 15 minute limit was implemented 2010-03-27: [Forced to wait before accepting an answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste/44099#44099)

Jeff Atwood♦:

> edit: this is implemented. I think 15 minutes (the current setting) is
> completely reasonable; if you're accepting earlier than that, it's
> irresponsible IMO as others haven't even had a chance to even LOOK at
> it.

### 48 hour accept own delay

It "appears" the accept your own was implemented "on or around" 01-06-09, as per Jeff in this blog post:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

And the initial roll out looks to have been included the 48 hour limitation.

So your 48 hour wait limit looks to have been implemented 01-06-09.

---

You can track various site changes here:
[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/74243#74243)

---

> And does this rule vary depending on the op's reputation?

No.

[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: the feature changes link is helpful

Comment: We need to get the gist of that into the help folks are shown when they try to do it sooner.

Comment: @james DOes this rule vary depending on the op's reputation ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. The rules are just basic and straight forward, and not really to control anything other than stopping people accepting the first answer that comes along to give others a chance of answering (or their own).