# Regarding the time that must pass between posting and acceptance of an answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Correct me if I'm wrong but AFAIK:

1. There is a time required to pass between an answer being posted and the questioner being able to accept it;
2. This time is much longer (2 days!) if the answer is a self-answer; this is correct at least on Math SX, where I just self-answered this and upon trying to accept I found myself confronted with:

> You can accept your own answer in 2 days.

[image]

3. However, I have the impression this time lapse significantly varies between sites; for example, if I remember well, I tried to self-accept my self-answer to [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/hakka-song-kam-thung-sim-character-approximation-and-translation-required-for) though convinced it would complain about this time lapse, and it got accepted, much to my surprise.

So I am asking:

1. How much time must there pass between when an answer is posted and when it is accepted?
2. Is this site-specific or system-wide?
3. Why is the time lapse for self-answers so much longer than for other answers?
4. And above all, **why exactly does this time lapse even exist?** Couldn't it just be eliminated? Is there a reason for forcing an accepter to wait, potentially causing him to load other questions and forget about the answer he was going to accept? And this "potentially" part is not just a guess at a possibility, but my memory of stumbling on an old question of mine and being surprised I had not yet accepted an answer when I surely had decided to accept it ages before…

Comment: The reasons are linked in the confirmation of your other questions.

Comment: I'm afraid «this question already has an answer here» is not true. But since the question has an answer, I guess I can be sure it won't be deleted, and thus not care if it gets closed or not :).

Comment: Yes, well you asked 4 questions and I couldn't close it as a duplicate of that many, so I suggested a question that answered 2 of them and had links in answering those 2 to the remainder of your question. A little bit of searching first would have answered them all, or lacking that only asking one question per question would make the whole process a lot easier.

Comment: Also, from the [deletion FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/179419) anyone with 10k can vote to delete after 48 hours. It's against convention to do so to a duplicate though and there's no real reason to think it'd happen in this case.

Comment: Uh-huh. Well, duplicate or not, this question -- it seems to me -- condenses information that is otherwise spread out on a question and several answers to another one, so it is still useful to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [question this one was suggested as a duplicate of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) didn't really answer me on its own, but two links in the answer, [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post) and [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) completed it. I am posting this to spare other users the trouble of reading through all the answers to link 1, and looking at the other two linked questions as well, and also to provide my own opinion on this time limit.

1. The [question this is not-too-much-of-a-duplicate of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) answers point 1:

> All must wait 15 minutes after asking to accept

> All must wait 48 hours to accept own answer

2. By the way it's termed, it's system-wide.
3. This wasn't really answered, but I guess it's just to make it more likely for self-answers not to be accepted, for in most cases other users' answers are better in that they come from users who have more experience and are therefore more likely to be both correct and good practice; however, if someone seeds a question, he might want to just share some knowledge he knows to be correct, and this delay gets in the way. But maybe that "answer your own question" checkmark under the question box was designed for this… The situations in which the long period gets in *my* way are when a question is answered in comments and I want to sum up what those comments say in order to isolate it and make it prominent, perhaps even adding my own bit of research; examples: [1](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/hakka-song-kam-thung-sim-character-approximation-and-translation-required-for), which was something like the hardest question I ever asked, and still has some little issues, [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392145/where-does-that-dimension-equality-come-from), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998451/conformality-of-a-map), 4 where the 2 days haven't passed yet, [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1389977/trouble-understanding-proof-of-this-proposition-on-contact-type-hypersurfaces), [6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750817/matrix-graph-and-irreducibility) - well I don't remember if it actually got in the way in this case, and this is very particular in that I self-answered because no-one had paid attention to the question, not because comments had answered it -, [7](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151679/installing-the-mcq-tex-package), which I only just accepted, [8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220475/customizing-theorem-list), [9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152791/superimposing-characters-in-text-mode-pdftex), [10](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167593/special-theorem-command), [11](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152231/typesetting-problem-xetex) another one I only just accepted, and I am going to stop searching.
4. Yes, there are reasons. I will discuss the pros and cons below.

**Pros**

- As the accepted answer to the first "1" link goes:

> Anyone who accepts an answer within, say, 15 minutes of posting their question is almost by definition being lazy in a bad way. That is, they're accepting the first answer that comes along without considering all their options.

- > There have been several situations where I arrive on a question and have something new to add to the discussion or solution, but simply hit the back button because an answer has already been accepted. Maybe that's wrong of me, but I only have a limited number of hours in the day, and I'd rather spend them productively.

In other words, users coming to questions with accepted answers might, even when the accepted answer is wrong, be discouraged from posting their own, as this user reports from personal experience.

- > I believe you lost the points if your accepted answer is unaccepted so having a waiting period before an answer could be accepted might cut down on hard feelings because of changing accepted answers.
- Accepting answers bumps questions off the unanswered list, so if a "bad" answer is posted and accepted, the question gains less attention, and is thus less likely to get another better answer.

**Cons**

- > If I found the exact answer within 5 minutes, why wouldn't I be able to accept it ? Often see questions like "this is not working, help" with an answer like "do this, it'll fix it".
- > There's no reason a question can't be answered faster.
- > There's no reason a question *will* be answered correctly after the time lapse.
- > One-shot users will simply not accept the answer and never return to the site.
- > We have notifications, so if a new answer is posted, the OP is alerted and they can change their mind, especially if the new answer points out flaws in the accepted answer.
- > the OP knows best whether the answer worked for them or not.

In other words, even if another answer is better, the OP might still choose the "worse" one because it helps them the most.

- > The effect of preventing or even discouraging people from accepting an answer immediately is going to be overall negative. We've already had to put measures in place to encourage people to accept answers more, and many, many, many comments posted are devoted to asking the OP to accept an answer.
- > Keep in mind that the community's highest voted answer appears immediately below the accepted answer.
- > Since we have community involvement in voting, the best answer can be voted up by the community.

> Granted, this doesn't help questions that are asked and answered very quickly -- but if the answer fixed the problem for the asker, why mess with it?

> If you have a better answer, posting it will cause the post to be 'bumped'. [Doing this at a high use time of day](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/the-best-time-to-ask-a-stack-overflow-question/) will almost guarantee upvotes if your answer is better.

- Especially with self-answers, as discussed above, there are cases in which the time lapse merely gets in the way and can cause non-acceptance because the OP loads other questions during the lapse and forgets he has to accept his answer.

With all that, I guess I am against this time lapse. I mean, accepted answers are not meant to be the best, but rather the most helpful, and the quick answers, even if wrong, are often decidedly more helpful than better, slower answers, because being quicker they get adopted sooner and get the OP going where he previously was stuck on his problem. And who are we to get in the way of the poster telling us "problem solved"? Besides, I even had a couple of times when I wanted to accept a very good answer by someone else, which was the only present answer (and I guess still is), had come after ages of commenting, and I was stopped because of the time lapse! I actually had to wait those x minutes or seconds to accept the only answer *there would ever be* to that question! Does that make sense?

**Update:**
This time imposition seems to be bugged, since I just self-answered and accepted in a timespan of less than 10s:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is the answer. It is accepted. It is by me, who asked the question, and it is "answered just now". Here is some data about the question:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

And [this is the question in question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419525/passage-in-proving-lagrangian-subspaces-have-lagrangian-complements). So the question arises: [is there a maximum time a question can stay up without answers or votes before the time delay on accepting self-answers is removed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266427/is-there-a-bug-in-the-time-delay-between-posting-a-self-answer-and-accepting-it)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWbmY.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRWmH.png

Comment: No bug. 48 hours must pass **from the time the question was posted**, not the answer.