# Is there a bug in the time delay between posting a self-answer and accepting it?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer, self-answer

This is a follow-up of the update to the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265874/regarding-the-time-that-must-pass-between-posting-and-acceptance-of-an-answer). After that question, I thought *everyone* had to wait 2 days before accepting a self-answer. Yet today, as the answer says, I posted and accepted a self-answer in less than 10s. Here are images that prove it:

[image: "answered just now" and accepted]

"answered just now" and accepted

[image: Data about the question]

Data about the question.

The link to the question can be found on the linked question's answer. So is there a bug in this time delay feature? Or is there a maximum time after which the time delay is removed from a question which has received no answers, votes, or comments in that time from posting? And if so, what is that time and what are the precise rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant age here is the age of *the question.* Both the 15-minute waiting period (for accepting *any* answer) and the 48-hour waiting period (for accepting *your own* answer) are imposed **starting from the time the *question* is created** - and your question was already over a week old by the time you posted the answer.

The purpose of the delay is to ensure that others are not discouraged from posting answers to the question by the presence of a quickly-written and quickly-accepted answer; once sufficient time has been allowed for others to contribute, both delays are lifted.

#### See also:

- [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)
- [Discourage questions being marked as answered within an hour or so of being posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post/44099#44099)