# Warn users before accepting an answer too fast

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

Many people accept answers immediately when it answers their question. However, if they had given it more time, they can receive more answers that may be better than the original. Similar to the "Remember you can accept this answer" message box, I think a message should appear when the question poster hovers over the accept answer button.

This message would say something along the lines of "Are you sure you want to accept this answer? If you wait longer, you may receive better answers." (just wrote that up to get a rough idea of what it may say). The message would appear if the question was asked recently, maybe 6 hours at least.

What do you guys think?

Comment: I'd prefer to just disallow acceptance until 24 hours after the question is asked. That ensures every user has had an opportunity to contribute an answer during their typical SE logged-in period, and that any answers can be revised if possible before another one is accepted and the answerers don't see a point in making improvements.

Comment: Are you only interested in what the guys think?

Comment: There is already a [wait time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-post), why nag them even after that?

Comment: If it answers the question, job done. Why wait?

Comment: @UmarAta well im not saying that they cant accept it, im just saying that a message appears when they hover over the button. They can still accept it, but it's just a message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, if they had given it more time, they can receive more answers
>   that may be better than the original.

Your question makes sense, but you're assuming that accepting an answer would somehow discourage users from posting new answers. Based on my experience, I don't think there is very close correlation between the two. The warning is not necessary because

1. You can change the acceptance whenever you want, as the [help center says](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers):

   > You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the
   >   answer, at any
   >   time
2. Accepted answer doesn't discourage users (especially those with enough experience) from posting a new answer.
3. It's a way of saying "thank you" for some users. We can't warn the OP against this graceful gesture.

You need to note that there are many users who post just one question and never come back after accepting an answer. Also, there are those who don't even know what acceptance is and how to accept an answer. Only experience and time spent on each site will help them.

The more important issue is how to differentiate well-researched and useful answers from under-researched and unhelpful answers. If upvoting and downvoting work in the way they have been designed, we don't have to worry about this acceptance issue.