# New Badge: Quick-Draw

Tags: discussion, status-declined, badges, accepted-answer, responses

**Quick-Draw:** First to respond, and with accuracy. Imagine a couple gun-slingers in the west. Being the first to respond means nothing if you miss the mark. Being the first to respond, and hitting the mark makes you the Quick-Draw.

**Rules:**

- Answer must be in within 3 minutes
- Answer must have 10+ upvotes
- Answer must be accepted
- Answer must have 2 or less Revisions
- Answer Latest Revision must be within the Quick-Draw window too

The date the answer is accepted doesn't matter. The only time-relationship that matters is the Answer-Submission time and the Question-Submission time - modifiers include Answer Revisions, etc.

Comment: I like this. I do see it as an upgraded Enlightened badge.

Comment: You'll get a lot of people earning this badge for 'joke' or 'pithy' answers. They are usually first, and they get a lot of upvotes.

Comment: I think you should also revise this suggestion to also include a more restrictive timeframe (or no timeframe allowance at all) for answer revision. That would immediately prevent people from posting first and then crafting a better response to get the badge.

Comment: devinb: Joke or pithy answers don't tend to get accepted as often as an actually useful answer. I would also say discount CW posts because they tend to have a higher tendency of those types of quick posts (I am guilty of them often myself).

Comment: Base the award on # of revisions too.

Comment: I would say that if you wanted this to be a gold-version of the enlightened badge, you should require a greater score than just +5. +10 or +25 are more in line with gold standards on SO.

Comment: You're right. +10 votes and accepted seems to be pretty solid.

Comment: So if you revise the answer a day later, you lose the badge? I don't think we want to discourage editing here. I think basing it on the timing of the votes is enough for this.

Comment: mmyers: I would say that once the badge is awarded it's awarded (just like all badges). If you win the badge and THEN revise the answer, I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @TXI, I missed the criteria of 'accepted' I thought it only had to be upvoted. I am thoroughly shamed.

Comment: @TheTXI: How would that fit in with awarding the badge at some point down the road when the answer finally gets accepted? Does that count or not? What if it was only accepted because of the edits? There are all sorts of edge cases here.

Comment: mmyers: I don't think that the timeframe of the acceptance (or how long it took for the votes) should matter as long as the answer itself remained within the allowable window. That would mean that as long as your post was in there fast and didn't get revised OUT of the allowable window, it would get the badge either A) during the time it is accepted if it already has the appropriate number of votes or B) when it gets the final necessary vote if it has already been accepted.

Comment: 3 minutes is shorter than the grace period for editing, so if the last revision was within the quick-draw time, only it would be shown.

Answer (score 25):

Please, **no**.

The site suffers enough from the [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/is-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-solved) problem. No need to encourage it.

Comment: I would think quick and quality responses is what would make this site pleasing and appealing.

Comment: FGITW isn't a negative thing. It is a positive thing.

Comment: People are desperate to answer quickly, rather than correctly.

Comment: There's a difference between a fast quality response and a fast garbage response.

Comment: devinb: If they don't answer correctly you don't accept the answer. That should be pretty obvious.

Comment: The site doesn't suffer from FGITW. It enjoys every second of it.

Comment: we had this badge initially and dropped it during the very early beta for this very reason.

Comment: I disagree. I think that FGITW is a real problem. It makes answering weird and competitive. Instead of being able to compose a proper answer, taking a few minutes to add links and check/compile everything, you have to post something quick and then edit, reedit.. I really dislike it. You would still have a fantastic great site if people could afford 5-10 minutes to draft a complete answer.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, how was it called back then :P?

Answer (score 10):

Isn't this what the [Enlightened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened) badge is for?

> First answer was accepted with at least 10 up votes. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Comment: Close. Enlightened is to Quick-Draw what Fanatic is to Woot :)

Comment: I think Quick-Draw should be like an upgraded version of the Enlightened badge. If you are first, get accepted, get voted up X times, and managed to get it under say...2 minutes, you get a gold badge.

Comment: ++ TheTXI       .

Comment: But it should have to be uploaded a LOT of times.
Also, how would we stop people from answering with a placeholder, then updating their answer later?

Comment: devinb: Do not allow the badge to be awarded on answers that were revised outside of the alotted time window (or answers that were revised at all if you are really that concerned about FGITW)

Comment: Let's see... My highest-voted answer got 37 votes and was accepted. It was posted 57 seconds after the question. Is that gold-badge-worthy?

Comment: mmyers: If it was not a CW answer, I would say yes.

Comment: This was my complete answer: "Because sets are not ordered. Some implementations are, but that is not a general property of sets.

If you're trying to use sets this way, you should consider using a list instead." -- Why should I be rewarded for stating the obvious? I did get two silver badges, but I don't see why a gold one is necessary. (I wouldn't turn it down, though. :D )

Comment: mmyers: I don't see why stating the obvious should be disqualified either.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that quick answers with a lot of quick upvotes are almost always for very shallow questions. (Then again, most gold badges are already given for shallow questions anyway, right?)

Comment: mmyers: I think you are seeing the light (gold) now

Comment: mmyers - there will always be some questions that get a lot of attention, even if they're silly. Can't change that :)

Comment: I like the description, kinda post fixed. First time vs. multiple times?

Answer (score 3):

I dunno. This is already how I get most of my rep points--do I really need to get badges for it, too?

Besides, there's already the Enlightened badge.

Answer (score 3):

Is the proposal that the answer just has to be *posted* within 5 minutes?

Answer posted + at least 5 upvotes + answer accepted, all within 5 minutes, would make more sense to me as something which encourages fast answers which are accurate from very early on - instead of an answer which is posted quickly but rubbish, then edited and eventually becomes good enough.

Comment: I would say posted within X minutes (I don't like 5, I think that's WAY too slow for a quick-draw), has Y up votes (say 10), and was accepted. Like I've said in other comments, I see this as almost a gold-version Enlightened badge.

Comment: With Z or less Revisions, or Last Revision Time is within the Quick-Draw window.

Comment: I don't think you can put a timeline on when it is accepted. Then it's reliant on the OP paying attention, and the answerer shouldn't be punished for that.

Comment: I don't think the accepted time is of importance. As long as the accepted answer fell within the correct time frame. In theory the badge could get awarded 30 days down the road after it had already accumulated 50 up votes and it was just then accepted (or even if it was accepted quickly but took 30 days to gain the appropriate number of up votes)

Comment: No, no timeline on when it's accepted...only when it's posted, relative to when the question was asked.

Answer (score 2):

The concept is clever, but I think the implementation is potentially tricky and might encourage undesired behavior. For example, how do you handle edits, does it only count if it's your original answer, no edits? Also, wouldn't this encourage simple, fast answers? Simple and fast answers are good and acceptable, but I don't think they need to be encouraged, which is the point of badges.

EDIT: In response to your edit. I understand the intent is for quality answers, however, unless N was quite high I believe it would likely encourage behavior that shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: If you think the simple-answer would get upvoted...do they get upvoted right now? Not really. The key here is the quality of the answer.

Comment: I agree. N couldn't be some small insignificant number. No more than Woot should be 3 days. It must be something admirable.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your own question shouldn't count. That'd be shooting yourself in the foot.

Trivia: I earned a necromancer badge for this suggestion in [Additional Badge Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/27010#27010). Turned out I was unwittingly guilty of being the slowest cheater in the east.

Comment: Why shouldn't it count? If it's got 10+ up votes, it'll be pretty good, even if you accept it yourself.

Comment: @Peter: If you already had the answer prepared when you asked the question, then that doesn't indicate that you're a quick draw. You should still get "Nice answer" and the like though.