# Feature Request: Response Time (Maybe a Badge)

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

This would really just be fun.  But it might be neat to have a badge or stat for the response time between a question is asked and an accept answer is given.  So it would be the time between the original question and the original answer (Time of when it is actually accepted doesn't matter). Edited answers would probably have to exempted so as not encourage people just putting something in a fast as possible and then editing it.

For example, a Badge might be something *like*:

"The Flash: Gave 100 unedited accepted answers within 20 seconds of the question being asked."

Comment: Similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1289/new-badge-quick-draw

Comment: The time limit on accepted answers(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste) would limit the Flash to a minimum of 15 minutes.

Comment: heavyd: No, not really,  because when it is accepted doesn't matter.

Comment: I think SO/SU/SF/M already has enough of a "Fastest Gun in the West" problem.

Comment: I vote bad idea :-)  Moderator feel free to reject/close.

Answer (score 5):

There is already the [Enlightened Badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened).

I think this is enough encouragement for giving good, quick answers. The FGITW issue is already a big enough problem.

Comment: Seconded. The "The Flash" idea is nice but the side-effects of thousands of people trying to get it would probably be counter-productive for the site as a whole.

Comment: A good point about the enlightened Badge.  I guess I didn't  of the FGITW problem as much because I really don't think it is much of an issue on serverfault.com (where I hang out).

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Jon, too many times someone will submit a vague answer just to be first.  Later they go back and add content that should have originally been added.

Comment: This is a "Fastest Gun In The West" answer.

Comment: Actually, I do this a lot, not because I didn't want to add the content at first, but to reply to comments and add examples I think might be helpful based on the discussion that has evolved.  Editing isn't always about rep-gaming.

Comment: @rlb except that it was about 15 mintues behind Jon, but yes I completely agree.   @Popular Im not saying everyone does it for that reason but I know some do.