# Extending partial answer or posting answer with additional info?

Tags: discussion, answers

Often there is a situation, when there is already an answer which is correct, but either it's only partial or does not go at all into details, culprits etc.

Which would be preferred way of dealing with that:

- extend existing answer? even if that means your contribution will be actually more then original answer?
- write separate answer without duplicating content of the one(s) already posted?
- write complete answer duplicating content already posted? (won't that be perceived as ["answer stealing"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27724/answer-stealers)?)

Answer (score 4):

I sometimes write an additional answer. That mentions that it is an addition (probably with reference to the answer).

If there is not that much extra information, you can add it to the answer.

You should never copy the original answer without any reference.